# R data.frame not show Chinese Character properly

Tags: r, machine-learning, gmm

[image: topics]

Hello everyone. Above link is a `data.frame` in R, each column contains ten topics(in terms of single Chinese word). I got that as result of self-implemented Gaussian Mixture Model(for highly sparse matrix).

As you can see, the appearance of R `data.frame` is awkward, columns are not aligned (as of normal ASCII). So my question is : is there some way to show the R `data.frame` of Chinese Character properly?